# How to make dynamic HTML, that changes its content depending what you click on

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been working on my dynamic web form of Periodic Table of Elements. I made the HTML, CSS .... so structure and styling of my PTE.

Then I wanted to make my PTE dynamic using JS.

So, my main goal is:
When you click on element, PTE will disappear and it will load content into one HTML page, which is the same for every element. But the content has to change depending what element you click on.

I hope you will understand my problem.

Here is for example Hydrogen table cell (without CSS):

```
    <td class="nonmetal">
        <a id="first_element">  
            <strong class="symbol">H</strong>
            <span class="atomic_number">1</span>
            <em class="name">Hydrogen</em>
            <span class="atomic_weight">1.008</span>
        </a>
    </td>
```

And here is simple piece of HTML code into which I want to transfer information about element (history of e., physical properties....)

```
<body>
    <h1>About element</h1>
    <p>Content</p>
    <h2>History</h2>
    <p>Content</p>        
</body>
```

Maybe Ill need some text document with info from which Ill transfer info about element. Thats why I need help.

Thanks for all responses.

Comment: So unfortunately this question is a little too broad for me to answer in this format. I think you need to read about how to manipulate the DOM using JS and come back with specific questions. There are a million different ways to do what you are asking. It would be like if I came to you and said "how do I build facebook?" I know you are building a much simpler web app, but the point is the same. You know what I mean?

Comment: For DOM manipulating i suggest to check for something like angular, or vue.js